# Populate data classes with values from linkedhashmap

Tags: kotlin

I have a linkedhashmap that has the following shape: `<String, Subject>`. The class Subject has the following fields:

```
class Subject {
var name: Boolean? = null
var lastname: Boolean? = null
var location: Boolean? = null
 ..
 }


 final_result = 
 "admin" -> Subject
 "customer" -> Subject
 etc.
```

I need to populate data classes that have the following format:

```
data class SubjectSummary(
    val admin: SubjectData,
    val customer: SubjectData
    ...
)
    
data class SubjectData(val details: DetailsData)


data class DetailsData(val name:String, val lastName:String ...)
```

Because I need to serialize the SubjectSummary class and get the following json format:

```
{
 "admin": {
   "details": {
      "name": "",
      "lastname": "",
       ...
     }
  }
 "customer": {
   "details": {
      "name": "",
      "lastname": "",
       ...
     }
  }
```

}

How do I assign the final_result map to match the SubjectSummary structure? I have done it with simple data classes, but when the fields within the data class are data classes, I'm not sure hot to populate it. Any guidance?
For simplicity I'm only showing a small example with a few fields.

Comment: Java tag removed as your code looks to be all Kotlin

Comment: Does `DetailsData` contain the same fields as `Subject`? If so, why bother with a separate class?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal with this transformation is just to be able to serialize with the given JSON format, then you don't need this `SubjectSummary` class. A `Map<String, SubjectData>` would be sufficient and probably more convenient to create when transforming from the initial map.

Also, it seems that `DetailsData` contains the same fields as `Subject`. If that's the case there is no need for an extra class either.

So in the end it seems you just need to create a `Map<String, SubjectData` where `SubjectData` could be defined as `data class SubjectData(val details: Subject)`. You can transform your initial map pretty easily then:

```kotlin
val transformed = finalResult.mapValues { (_, subject) -> SubjectData(subject) }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! The data contained is not the same, as for example for every field in DetailsData I need to add created/updated timestamps etc. I have removed all other computations that might make the question hard to understand and am trying to understand how to populate a LinkedHashMap to a Data Class format, regardless of the shape

Comment: @MiraM there is no easy way to map a `Map` to a data class (apart from dirty reflection), because maps are inherently dynamic, while the fields in a data class are well known. But my point was that you don't need a data class to represent such JSON. If the keys in JSON represent something dynamic and the values are of the same type, it's really ok (and advised) to use a `Map<String, T>` to represent it.